# QSqlDatabase LNK2019 error

Tags: qt, linker-errors, lnk2019

I tried to compile the following code in Qt 5.0.0:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtSql/QSql>
#include <Qtsql/QSqlDatabase>
#include <QStringList>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QStringList db = QSqlDatabase::drivers();
    return a.exec();
}
```

and I received this error:

> main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class QStringList __cdecl QSqlDatabase::drivers(void)" (__imp_?drivers@QSqlDatabase@@SA?AVQStringList@@XZ) referenced in function _main
>
> debug\test.exe:-1: error: LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

I have added `QT += sql` in my `.pro`. What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `QtSql.lib` ( you can find the name of Qtsql exactly in QT/lib in your computer) by go to Project/Properties/Configuration properties/Linker/Input, add `QtSql.lib` to Additional Dependencies

P.S. I used to face this error, and the error is fixed by this way. Good luck